# Upgrading Angular from 1.1.5 -> 1.4 : right click stopped working

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I have a fairly complicated app that I have finally begun the upgrading process from angular 1.1.5 -> 1.4.

One issue I've been having that I can't seem to find an answer to is my right click stopped working.  Specifically, in `Chrome: Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)` to access the menu that allows inspecting elements.

Has anyone had similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to empty my cache on chrome, my bad.

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. It explains the cause and solution of the problem.